# ¿como haria yo para saber si un campo de un modelo en django ha sido actualizado?

Tags: django, django-admin

Tengo un modelo en Django en lo cual necesito validar si un campo en especifico ha sido actualizado, partiendo de eso realizare una acción, les agradecería su ayuda. el campo que quiero validar es asignar, solo necesito su capturar su valor para compararlo con el nuevo valor. tengo conocimiento de que los signals en django hace lo que yo necesito

```
class Insidencia(models.Model):
autor = models.ForeignKey(User)
categoria = models.ForeignKey(Categoria, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
asunto = models.CharField(verbose_name="Asunto", max_length=255)
fecha = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True,blank=True)
descripcion = models.TextField(verbose_name="Descripcion")
URGENCIA = (
    ('FUERA DE SERVICIO','Fuera de Servicio'),
    ('OPERACION DEGRADA','Operacion Degradada'),
    ('FALLAS INTERMITENETE','Fallas Intermitente'),
    ('FALLAS NO GRAVE','Fallas no Grave'),
    ('FALLA OCASIONAL', 'Falla Ocasional'),
)
urgencia = models.CharField(verbose_name="Urgencia", choices=URGENCIA, max_length=50)
soluciion = models.TextField(verbose_name='Solucion', blank=True, null=True)
asignar = models.ForeignKey('Tecnico',blank=True ,null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
ESTADO = (
    ('EN PROCESO', 'En Proceso'),
    ('RESUELTO','Resuelto'),
)
estado = models.CharField(verbose_name="Estado", choices=ESTADO, max_length=50, blank="True", default='EN PROCESO',)

class Meta:
    verbose_name_plural = u'Insidencias'

def __encode__(self):
    return self.asunto
```

Answer (score 0):

En efecto Django signals puede serte util yaq que posee metodos para cuando un modelo recibe un save o un delete por ejemplo (la documentación aun no esta en español) pero el codigo es simple y comprensible:

[Django signals](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/2.0/topics/signals/)

Sin embargo, puedes simplificarlo notificando tu mismo en la vista que crees para modificar el modelo ya sea por correo o con mensajes en pantalla.Te adjunto ejemplos:

[Enviar correo en Django](http://www.elwebmaster.com/general/envio-de-emails-con-django)

Y para mensajes en django usando el mismo framework haces la importación:

```
from django.contrib import messages
```

Y luego dentro de la vista:

```
messages.success(request, 'Cambio realizado')
```

Para mas info de messages, consulta la documentación:

[Django messages](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/messages/)